# Relationship between $f$ and its derivative $f'$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

I have been starting to learn derivatives and finding the equation of the tangent of a curve. However, I am a bit confused as to how to solve this question:

> Let $f$ be a differentiable function such that $f(0)=7$ and let $g(x) = x f'(x)$. Evaluate $g′(0)$.

For context, I understand the basics of differentiation(finding the derivative) and how to find the equation of the tangent. However, what I am not clear on is: what is the relationship between f(x) and its derivative? I feel like the question above requires some manipulation of f(x) and f'(x) and using tangent equations to solve this. If anyone can please explain the solution to the above question, that'll be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Solution to your posted question requires the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule).  Note that (for example) $~\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} f'(x) = f''(x).$

Comment: Your quoted question does not have enough information to answer it.  If $g(x)=xf'(x)$ then $g'(x)=f'(x)+xf''(x)$ and you seem to know nothing about $f'(0)$.  Perhaps you have mistyped it and it should have said $g(x)=xf(x)$

Comment: Per the comment of @Henry, there are three possibilities: [1] You have omitted a pertinent fact, namely that $f'(0)$ must have been given. [2] This pertinent fact was not omitted, and the problem composer intends that the answer be given in terms of the (unspecified) $f'(0)$.  [3] The problem composer made a mistake, and omitted a pertinent fact from the problem, thus creating a problem that can not be solved.

Comment: It may be intended that $f'(0)=7$ since the value of $f(0)$ is irrelevant to the answer. Note also that it is not given that $f$ is twice differentiable (see @Henry's comment), so it may also be that $g(x)=xf(x)$ is intended. Please check the source and confirm that the question is correct.

Comment: @MarkBennet Nice rebuttal to my comment.  It never occurred to me that $f$ might not be twice differentiable.

Comment: $g'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)$